# attr_encrypted not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encryption

Ruby 1.9.2p180, Rails 3.0.8, attr_encrypted 1.2.0

So, in my model I have the following:

```
attr_encryptor :email, :key => "awesome_key"
```

And in the database I have a text column named "encrypted_email".

In the console, everything works in memory.  The encrypted_email attribute is updated with the encrypted version and everything.  But when I go to save it, nothing happens.

While messing around with it I discovered that the model's changes hash does not reflect the changes to encrypted_email, even if I try to set the value manually.

Am I doing something wrong here or is attr_encrypted broken?  Does anyone know how things get added to the changes hash?  Is there some method call or something that I could add the setter methods that attr_encrypted generates so that changes show up in the hash?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the logs show an update statement that contains encrypted_email? I'm using Rails 3.0.10 with attr_encrypted 1.2.1 with no problems. I have attr_encrypted :ssn, :key => 'whatever', :encode => true. attr_encryptor is supposed to be aliased to do the same thing.

Comment: @BrianDeterling Thanks.  I forgot about this question... I should probably close it.  There was a bug in attr_encrypted regarding how it created getters and setters.  As a result, the data values didn't get flagged as changed and didn't get saved to the DB (hence so update statement in the logs).  I did a quick monkey patch on my end to resolve the issue.  I didn't submit my patch to the community because I didn't feel it was "worthy" if you know what I mean :-)  At some point someone with better Ruby skills submitted a patch and fixed it.

Comment: @brettish: Could you publish your patch as a Gist on GitHub or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the community fixed the bug.  Back when I was trying to make it work I just in the wrong place at the wrong time apparently :-)

Comment: in which version of gem it is fixed? can you publish you patch as Gist?